# alasql - Data source number 0 in undefined ,simple Javascript object as source then query, gives this error

Tags: alasql

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/alasql/0.3/alasql.min.js"></script>


var ProductList = JSON.parse('[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Shoes"},{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Chocolate"}]');


alasql("CREATE TABLE Products (ProductID INT, ProductName string)");

alasql.tables.Products = ProductList; // when inspect, the table is present

var x = alasql("SELECT * FROM Products order by ProductID"); //throws error
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it.

db.tables.Products.data - I was missing the data.

Parsing was not required.

```
var db = new alasql.Database();

db.exec("CREATE TABLE Products (ProductID INT, ProductName string)");

var ProductList = [{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Shoes"},{"ProductID":2,"ProductName":"Chocolate"}];

db.tables.Products.data = ProductList;

var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM Products");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you shared, I see that you haven't give json data source.

You can fix it by ...

```
var x=alasql("Select * FROM ?  ORDER BY ProductID",[Products])
```